# How to change Windows folder permission with VB.NET? (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)

Tags: windows, vb.net, directory, permissions, filesystems

I am working on this small VB.NET application which needs to copy a couple files to a Windows folder but I am getting an access denied error; then if I go to the folder, right-click it and manually write the write permission to the folder everything will work fine.

However this application is going to be used by our employees in several machines of the network and mostly of them has not this level of "expertise" meaning that the process must happen smoothly and automatically and therefore the change of the permission should be done by the application itself.

I found a code snippet online which supposed to fix the problem but it is not working for me. I am getting a runtime error with the following message:

*System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.'*

And this is the code I am using:

```
Dim folder As String = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\MyApp"
Dim sid As SecurityIdentifier = New SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, Nothing)
Dim writerule As FileSystemAccessRule = New FileSystemAccessRule(sid, FileSystemRights.Write, AccessControlType.Allow)
Dim fsecurity As DirectorySecurity = Directory.GetAccessControl(folder)

fsecurity.AddAccessRule(writerule)
Directory.SetAccessControl(folder, fsecurity) 'the error happens here
```

The error happen exactly in the line where the permission setting try to apply. Any idea?

Comment: Simply don't use `Program Files` as storage. You have the User's `AppData` (Local or Roaming) or the CommonAppData folder (the `ProgramData` directory created in the root of the disc where the System is installed).

Comment: @Jimi the problem is not with using 'Program Files'. I tried **c:\myfolder** and the problem persists. I still need to change permissions. 

Comment: That's why I suggested to use those standard (System-generated) paths as storage: you always have read/write access there.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to level up the privileges of the application. Here it is how to force the program to do it automatically without the need of right-click it and choose "run as administrator" every time:

https://mobitek-system.com/blog/2020/06/how-to-run-vb-net-code-as-an-administrator/